# error enum has no member when using macro

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I want create two enums: `DerivedBirdType` and `BasicBirdType`. BasicBirdType has members named like BCT_*. DerivedBirdType has all members in BasicBirdType but with different prefix DCT_*, and it also has members not in BasicBirdType.

For example, BasicBirdType has two members, *BCT_waterfowl* and *BCT_loons*. and DerivedBirdType will have *DCT_waterfowl*, *DCT_loons* and a new member *DCT_Obama*.

I have 3 files. `Bird.h` declares the enums structure and token-parsing operator which reuse the common names. `DerivedBirdType.h` reuse the members in `BasicBirdType.h` and add extra members.

The problem is `BasicBirdType` now has no member "BCT_waterfowl" when I tried to get BCT_*, while `DerivedBirdType` works fine.

```
BasicBirdType bird1 = BasicBirdType::BCT_waterfowl; // enum `BasicBirdType` now has no member "BCT_waterfowl"
DerivedBirdType bird2 = DerivedBirdType::DCT_waterfowl; // works fine
```

Bird.h:

```
#pragma once
#define BASIC_BIRD_TYPE(type) BCT_##type,
#define DERIVED_BIRD_TYPE(type) DCT_##type,

namespace Bird
{
    enum DerivedBirdType
    {
        #include "DerivedBirdType.h"
        TotalDerivedBirdTypes
    };

    enum BasicBirdType
    {
        #include "BasicBirdType.h"
        TotalBasicBirdTypes
    };
}
```

DerivedBirdType.h:

```
#pragma once
#define BASIC_BIRD_TYPE(type) DERIVED_BIRD_TYPE(type)

#include "BasicBirdType.h"
DERIVED_BIRD_TYPE(Obama)
```

BasicBirdType.h:

```
#pragma once
BASIC_BIRD_TYPE(waterfowl)
BASIC_BIRD_TYPE(loons)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your problem is that the header file "BasicBirdType.h" is already included when you included header file "DerivedBirdType.h", Therefore when you included BasicBirdType in the Basic enum, the compiler removes it as it being already included

```
enum BasicBirdType
{
    #include "BasicBirdType.h"    // no effect, file already included
    TotalBasicBirdTypes
};
```

This is the reason that the BasicBirdType enum is empty apart from TotalBasicBirdTypes

Comment: You are right. It works after I removed the `#pragma once` in BasicBirdType.h so the file can be includes twice. But it will slow the build time, do you have other ideas?

Comment: If you want to design your code to require including a file more than once then you need to pay the cost of doing so.  For this usage, I doubt it's much of an issue.